# What is making our Action Creator available as props in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchWeather } from '../actions/index';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { term: '' };

    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  }

  onFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.fetchWeather(this.state.term);
    this.setState({ term: '' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="input-group">
        <input
          placeholder="Get a five-day forecast in your favorite cities"
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.term}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
        />

        <span className='input-group-btn'>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">
            Submit
          </button>
        </span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchWeather }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

At one point in this tutorial, the author says that `mapDispatchToProps` hooks up our Action Creator `fetchWeather` to our component. But does it? Doesn’t it dispatch the action from our Action Creator to our reducers?

What is actually making this available in our component as `props`?

Comment: `mapDispatchToProps` **maps the dispatch function to props**. You can additionally bind your action creators and map that to props to remove `dispatch(…)` call boilerplate

Comment: So that function is what actually what allows us to call `this.props.fetchWeather`? Where in the docs is this?

Comment: Yes. It *connects* a component to allow it to dispatch actions to change the global store. See [the documentation](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options). If you don't specify `mapDispatchToProps`, it automatically passes the dispatch function to the component as a prop, but you can bind the action creator so you don't have to call dispatch (it will do it internally).

Comment: oh so the call to mapDispatchToProps override allows us to not have to call dispatch in the component. So it seems like the mapDispatchToProps allows us to connect the Action Creator `fetchWeather` to redux and the reducers... but what part of this code makes the `fetchWeather` available as a prop?

Comment: You can choose to bind dispatch to it with `bindActionCreator`. You're calling  `connect`, which is **higher order component**. Internally, `connect` passes the global store and dispatch/bound action creators via what you pass as `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchProps`. `connect` renders the component you pass to it, along with connecting it to the Redux store.

Answer (score 1):

You can have

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { fetchWeather };
```

instead of

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchWeather }, dispatch)
}
```

Anyway this is the block that makes your action creator available via `this.props`.

Comment: But then what is the connect doing?

Comment: The last line in you file which is `export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);` is the exact place where the connection happens.

Comment: The connection to props?

Comment: Connect method is some sort of a wrapper which takes you component (SearchBar) and returns a new one with the props from mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps. So it is the place where it all happens.